# Como puedo ajustar tablas html para que se genere una tabla por pagina con la libreria Dompdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf, dompdf

He estado creando un pdf dinámico. Dependiendo de los datos ingresados se me van generando las tablas y he tenido el problema que las tablas se desordenan en el pdf. Lo ideal es que se genere una tabla por hoja ¿Alguien tiene una posible solución?

La tabla y los atributos de las tablas las he dejado como sm para que no sea tan grande, ya que la tabla trae muchos datos dependiendo de los meses. Este es el código de mi tabla:

```
<div class="jumbotron p-2 bg-white shadow">
<!-- Inicia query 2 a programacarga -->
<?php
    $query0=$conn->prepare("SELECT programacarga.idProgramacarga, programacarga.seDistNave, 
                    programacarga.fechaEmisionPrograma, naves.nombre, tiponaveoperacion.seDistNave, naves.nombre
                    FROM programacarga
                    JOIN naves ON naves.seDistNave = programacarga.seDistNave
                    JOIN tiponaveoperacion ON tiponaveoperacion.seDistNave = programacarga.seDistNave
                    WHERE programacarga.fechaEmisionPrograma = '$fechaProgramaFiltro' 
                    GROUP BY programacarga.seDistNave
                    ORDER BY naves.nombre ASC");

   $query0->execute();
   $result=$query0->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   
   foreach ($result as $row) {
        $seDistNave = $row['seDistNave'];
        $nombreNave = $row['nombre'];
?>
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th colspan="4" class="bg-dark text-light small text-center">PROGRAMA DE CARGA</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th colspan="4" class="bg-secondary small text-light text-center"><?php echo $nombreNave?></th>  
</tr>
<tr>
    <th class="bg-secondary small text-light text-center">FECHA</th>
    <th class="bg-secondary small text-light text-center">CLIENTE</th>
    <th class="bg-secondary small text-light text-center">ORIGEN</th>
    <th class="bg-secondary small text-light text-center">DESTINO</th>
 </tr>  
 </thead>
 <tbody>
<?php
   $query1=$conn->prepare("SELECT programacarga.idProgramaCarga, programacarga.seDistNave, programacarga.idCliente, programacarga.fechaPrograma,
                            programacarga.fechaEmisionPrograma, programacarga.origen, programacarga.destino, tiponaveoperacion.seDistNave, naves.nombre AS nombreNave, clientesprogramacarga.nombreCliente
                            FROM programacarga
                            JOIN naves ON naves.seDistNave = programacarga.seDistNave
                            JOIN tiponaveoperacion ON tiponaveoperacion.seDistNave = programacarga.seDistNave
                            JOIN clientesprogramacarga ON clientesprogramacarga.idCliente = programacarga.idCliente
                            WHERE programacarga.fechaEmisionPrograma = '$fechaProgramaFiltro' AND programacarga.seDistNave = '$seDistNave'
                            ORDER BY programacarga.fechaPrograma");

   $query1->execute();
   $result=$query1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
   
   foreach ($result as $row) {
                            
        $nombreNave = $row['nombreNave'];
        $fechaPrograma = $row['fechaPrograma'];
        $cliente = $row['nombreCliente'];
        $origen = $row['origen'];
        $destino = $row['destino'];
        $seDistNave = $row['seDistNave'];
   ?>
   <tr>
       <td class="small"><?php echo $fechaPrograma?></td>
       <td class="small"><?php echo $cliente?></td>
       <td class="small"><?php echo $origen?></td>
       <td class="small"><?php echo $destino?></td>
   </tr>
   <?php } ?>
   <!-- termina query 2 a programacargar -->
   </tbody>
   </table>
```

Esta es la primera vez que uso la librería de dompdf, no tengo mucho conocimiento de ella. Aquí les dejo el código que usa esa librería:

```
<?php
//Guardamos en buffer el html y hacemos echo del html
$html = ob_get_clean();
//echo $html;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->set_option('dpi', 256);
$options = $dompdf->getOptions();
$options->set(array('isRemoteEnabled' => true));
$dompdf->setOptions($options);

//Carga el html en el Dompdf para transformar el archivo
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);

$dompdf->setPaper('letter');

$dompdf->render(); 
    
//Nombre del archivo pdf y si el Attachmet esta en true se descargara el documento al abrir el pdf si esta en false solo mostrara la vista previa
$dompdf->stream("$titulo.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));
?>
```

y aquí una imagen de como se me ven las tablas:

[image: Documento pdf generado]

Comment: Buenas, Diego, ¿a qué te refieres con que las tablas se desordenan? Desconozco esa librería, pero da la sensación de que genera el pdf a partir de tu página HTML. ¿No salen igual que en tu página? Supongo que si lo que quieres son saltos de página en tu pdf para separar tus tablas, eres tú el que debe indicarselo de alguna forma.

Comment: hola buenas @RubioRic, voy a probar colocar un salto de pagina dentro de un div

Comment: trate colocando dentro de un div style="page-break-after:always;" para realizar los saltos de pagina y no ha funcionado, el problema que tengo es que cada tabla tiene entre 30 a 31 registros mas una tabla pequeña con un solo dato, y sucede que por pagina me trae las tablas con 20 registros o menos y en la siguiente trae los registros restantes con la tabla con un solo dato.

Comment: ¿Puedes editar tu pregunta para indicar a qué te refieres con "desordenada", tal y como me has confirmado en tus comentarios? Por otro lado, como te decía no conozco esa librería, no sé exactamente cómo se fuerza un salto de página en ella, ni cuando quieres forzarlo tú. Era solo una sugerencia de investigación.

Comment: @RubioRic muchas gracias por tu sugerencia. Según lo que he estado leyendo si se puede forzar el salto de pagiga con una etiqueta style dentro de un div, probe aplicando tambien, <div style="page-break-before:always;">, si forzó un salto de página pero aún así me genera otros problemas, por ejemplo: crea una pagina en blanco, genera otra pagina pero con la tabla con la mitad de datos y entre otros.